# Does dopamine suppress serotonin production?

Tags: neuro-transmitters, dopamine, serotonin, happiness

In a [youtube video in spanish](https://youtu.be/0jnwEaBDwNA?t=135), I heard that dopamine suppress serotonin production. Is that true?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology and NeuroScience SE! When asking such a question, you might want to "show your work" and describe what partial answers your preliminary researches brought you.